# What is the difference between effective, real and nominal interest rate?

Tags: finance

I have been somewhat confused in financial math when to change the rates and the difference between effective, real and nominal rates. I still am confused after searching on Google and asking the teacher, so I was wondering if anyone had a more simplistic way of explaining it to get the overall idea. Thank you!

Comment: Hi Isabel, welcome to MSE. While your question seems to be somewhat related to mathematics, I think it would be (even) more appropriate to ask it on either this Stack Exchange page: https://quant.stackexchange.com/ , or this one: https://economics.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 3):

The **nominal interest rate** is the interest rate that does not take into account the effects of compound interest (or inflation, for that matter). I like to think about it in this way: say I put $\$1000$ in the bank that offers me a $5\%$ compound interest rate each month (my bank is very generous). Then, if I didn't know what compound interest was, I might assume that the interest accrued would be $12 \times 5 = 60\%$. The nominal annual interest rate in this case would be $60\%$.

However, this figure of $60\%$ does not take into account the effects of compound interest. In actual fact, after $1$ year my $\$1000$ would turn into
$$
1000 \times 1.05^{12} = \$1796 > \$1600
$$
So rather than going up by $60\%$, by money actually went up by $79.6\%$ (to one decimal place). This figure of $79.6\%$ is the **effective interest rate**-the interest accrued over the course of a year once the effects of compound interest have been taken into account.

Finally, the **real interest rate** is the interest rate once the effects of inflation have been taken into account. $\$1796$ might be the amount of money that you have after a year, but in that years the prices of goods will have risen, meaning that in practice $\$1796$ is worth less than it used to be.

Comment: I'd just add that nominal and effective interest rates are both always prior to accounting for inflation. It's not a different use of the term. Real interest rates account for inflation.

Comment: @AmaanM Thanks, I've edited that part out.