# When finding compound interest, the term "annual interest rate" seems misleading?

Tags: recurrence-relations, terminology, finance

The equation for compound interest can be derived by considering the recurrence relation
$a_{n+1}=a_n+sa_n=(1+r)a_n$ where $s>0$ is the growth rate, $a_n$ is the current balance, and $a_{n+1}$ is the new balance after one "compounding cycle." This gives
$$a_n=(1+s)^n a_0$$ where $n$ is the number of compounding cycles that have elapsed. Of course, this can be equation can be rewritten as $a_n=(1+s)^{mt}$ where $t$ is years and $m$ is number of compounding cycles per year. Typically, the compound interest equation is expressed as
$$a_n=\left(1+\frac{r}{m}\right)^{mt}a_0$$
where $r/m=s$, the compounding rate. Does $r$ have any meaning other than the compounding rate scaled by $m$? What I mean is....I find calling $r$ the "annual interest rate" very misleading. I would expect the annual interest rate to be the interest rate such that, were I to be compounding annually, the growth would match my original $a_n$ equation. As it stands, if I were to compound annually with the "annual interest rate" for $a_n$ I would get a completely different growth than $a_n$; that is, $a_n=\left(1+\frac{r}{m}\right)^{mt} \neq (1+r)^t$

How can this be reconciled? I suppose an answer would address why is $r$ called an annual rate and whether $r$ can be given any meaning other than its seemingly arbitrary definition.

Comment: I put a lot of thought into this question. I would love to hear justification for the downvote and vote to close.

Comment: See [What is the difference between effective, real and nominal interest rate?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4023146/13130) (FYI, I didn't downvote.)

Comment: @DaveL.Renfro would it be fair to say that the $r$ in question is a nominal rate? I come from a math background and am tutoring students taking financial math. I am unfamiliar with a lot of the relevant terminology.

Comment: I believe that's correct, namely that $r$ is the nominal rate. [This web page](https://global.oup.com/us/companion.websites/9780190296902/sr/interactive/formulas/nominal/) seems to have a nice discussion. I don't know "financial math" either, but I recall having to look this stuff up (even before the internet) because college algebra and precalculus texts were often unclear (to me) on this point. I'd look though a lot of such texts (library) until I found one that dealt with this issue.

Comment: FYI, another issue that often came up for me is explained in the paragraph beginning with "Another example is that ..." in [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4529267/13130).